# how to access multiple endpoints

Tags: wcf, endpoint, hosted

I have created a test WCF service WcfSampleLib with contract as IWcfSampleLib and ny service class is clsWcfSampleLib.

```
namespace WcfSampleLib
{
    public class clsWcfSampleLib:IWcfSampleLib
    {
        public string getMsg(string name)
        {
            return " HI " + name;
        }
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public  interface IWcfSampleLib
    {
         [OperationContract]
        string  getMsg(string name);
    }
}
```

Now I have added a window form application to host my WCF. I have created a App.config as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="Beh">
              <serviceMetadata  httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="http://{server}:9097"/>
              </behavior>
           </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>

      <service name ="WcfSampleLib.clsWcfSampleLib" behaviorConfiguration="Beh">
        <endpoint address="http://{server}:9096/SomeName" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract ="WcfSampleLib.IWcfSampleLib"/> 
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://{server}:9095/SomeName1" binding="netTcpBinding" contract ="WcfSampleLib.IWcfSampleLib"/>
      </service>

    </services>    
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I have two endpoints to use WCF from two different clients with different end point.
I have added following lines of code in Form1_Load event of Host Application

```
 host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WcfSampleLib.clsWcfSampleLib));
 host.Open();
 MessageBox.Show("started");
```

Now I can add reference of service with  http://{server}:9097 only. Is there any way so that I can use both endpoints with different URL means  net.tcp://{server}:9095/SomeName1 and http://{server}:9096/SomeName

Comment: Use the ServiceHost constructor that takes the base URI addresses collection - [ServiceHost Constructor (Type, Uri[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms585489.aspx)

Comment: i want to do it through config only